# Writing LINQ to XML query for filtering a xml string

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I have the following xml string:

```
<report>
    <item id="4219" Co="6063" LastName="Doe" FirstName="John"/>
    <item id="2571" Co="6063" LastName="Doe" FirstName="Jane"/>
</report>
```

How do I write a Linq to xml query that filters by name = "Jane" and writes it back to a xml string

I have the following code so far:

```
XDocument reportXmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(_report); //This is the string var assigned with data above
var filteredList = from x in fullReportXmlDoc.Descendants("item")
             where x.Attribute("FirstName").Value == "Jane"
             select x;
```

How do I convert filteredList back to a xml string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can project a new XML tree from your existing query:

```
var filteredList =
    from x in fullReportXmlDoc.Descendants("item")
    where x.Attribute("FirstName").Value == "Jane"
    select new XElement("report", x).ToString();
```

Or maybe, in a more general case:

```
string result = new XElement("report",
    from x in fullReportXmlDoc.Descendants("item")
    where x.Attribute("FirstName").Value == "Jane"
    select x).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `SaveOptions.DisableFormatting` to get the XElement's XML string?  It would look something like this for your case:

```
XDocument reportXmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(_report); //This is the string var assigned with data above
var elementStrings = from x in fullReportXmlDoc.Descendants("item")
    where x.Attribute("FirstName").Value == "Jane"
    select x.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```